Integral representation of Riemann Zeta function
While messing around with integrals of infinite series I arrived with the following equation: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left({\frac{1}{e^{2\pi x}-1}\left(\frac{d^a }{dx^a}\left(\frac{x^{a+1}}{x^2+1} \right)\right)}\right)dx=\frac{a!}{2}\zeta(a+1)-\frac{a!}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Is this equation or anything similar already known, or is this useful in any way?
